# How can I turn off 'Find My iPhone' after selling the phone?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

I just sold my old iPhone 4s, but it was still logged in to '*Find My iPhone*'. How can I log it out without having the phone? I have changed the password and told the person who bought it to see if they can log it out, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 6):

You can remotely remove the phone from your account using the [iCloud website](https://www.icloud.com/). Apple has a page with instructions on how to [remove your device from Find My iPhone](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2702?locale=en_US).

Answer (score 5):

Log into the [Find My iPhone](https://www.icloud.com/#find) part of the iCloud website.

Select your device from the drop-down list at the top of the screen.

Click on "Remove from Account".

This should remove your account from the device and enable the new owner to use it.

[image: Image of Remove from Account option]